# vb.net sql query counting

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have a sql database with 3 columns (board, line, defect)

The current sql query counts all the total amount of defects on the same board on the same line and populates a datagrid view.

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT board, count(defect) AS defect FROM [sqlccmdefects] WHERE [line] = @line GROUP BY board ORDER BY defect DESC" ' and date >= @startdata  AND date <= @enddata 

'SQL Command Params
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = mainform.line.Text
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@board", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = mainform.boardname.Text
```

The column "defect", has the values "contamination" or "violation". How would i alter the query to count the amount of "contamination" against the same board and same line, i've searched google and the brain isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Two options for you here:

1 - group by defect:

```
SELECT board, count(defect) AS defect FROM [sqlccmdefects] WHERE [line] = @line 
GROUP BY board, defect 
ORDER BY defect DESC
```

2 - add the defect into the where clause:

```
SELECT board, count(defect) AS defect FROM [sqlccmdefects] WHERE [line] = @line 
and defect = 'contamination'
GROUP BY board, defect 
ORDER BY defect DESC
```